# creating python lists on the fly and comparing them

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, set, comparison

I need to open multiple files and compare the contents of them. The way I am doing in now is dirty. I want to know an elegant way of doing it. I need to open multiple files and see the common elements between them.

My code looks like:

```
sample_1=[]
sample_3=[]
sample_2=[]
sample_4=[]

for line in open("sample_EC1.Regions","r"):
    line=line.strip()
    sample_1.append(line)


for line in open("sample_EC2.Regions","r"):
    line=line.strip()
    sample_2.append(line)


for line in open("sample_EC3.Regions","r"):
    line=line.strip()
    sample_3.append(line)


for line in open("sample_EC4.Regions","r"):
    line=line.strip()
    sample_4.append(line)

CommonRegions = list(set(sample_2)&set(sample_3)&set(sample_4)&set(sample_1))

print CommonRegions
```

This code is dirty as if the number of files increases, every time I need to change the code and if the number of files goes beyond 50, it is very difficult to edit the code every time.

Comment: for-loops. functions. abstract your hard-written code. DRY (*Don't Repeat Yourself*).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

t is a list of file names

```
b =[]

for fn in t:
    a=[]
    for line in open(fn,"r"):
        line=line.strip()
        a.append(line)
    b.append(set(a))

CommonRegions = set.intersection(*b)
print(CommonRegions)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! While the code in your answer looks good, it's always much better to add some explanation. This way future visitors of this site can easier find information. Explanations facilitate learning. As your answer has no explanation, it showed up in a review code for low quality.

Comment: Don't accumulate lines in a list and then build a set from it. Also, if any operation there fails, the open file is leaked, which can be fixed by opening it in a with-clause. The only upside to this is the call to `set.intersection()`, with the only caveat that it requires at least one set in `b`.

Answer (score 1):

```
total=4

with open("sample_EC1.Regions","r") as f:
    commonregions = {line.strip() for line in f}

for i in range(2,total+1):
    with open("sample_EC"+i+".Regions","r") as f:
        #set comprehension 
        sample = {line.strip() for line in f}
    commonregions = commonregions & sample

print commonregions
```

Instead of writing for loop for each file try to place them in a loop and perform intersection.

improvements:

1. Two important improvements, firstly make sure you close files again and secondly don't redundantly convert lists to sets: `with open(...) as f: s = {l.strip() for l in f}`. The thing with the "`for l in f`" is called a set comprehension, the "set comprehension" is an expression that generates a set on the fly

Comment: But the file names may not be the same every time.

Comment: Two important improvements, firstly make sure you close files again and secondly don't redundantly convert lists to sets: `with open(...) as f: s = {l.strip() for l in f}`. The thing with the "for l in f" is called a set comprehension, in case you need more info.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt can you edit my answer.a bit diffcult to understand in comments. feel free if u can edit my answer so that i too can learn or provide another answr

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt thank you , if u provide little explanation will be useful to many and u mention file close. where can we do that

Comment: The file is closed automatically because it is opened in a with-clause. This should be the default way of opening files, otherwise you need a try-catch-finally and close() it there. Note that it doesn't matter for "short" programs, because the OS will close them automatically, too, but you can't have an unlimited number of files open, so you generally want to reuse them. Then, the "set comprehension" is an expression that generates a set on the fly. You will probably find much more on the web about list comprehensions, but set comprehensions are a natural extension then.

Answer (score 0):

The most elegant way to do this is to use [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and set comprehensions:

```
def file_to_set(path):
    with open(path, "r") as f:
        return {line.strip() for line in f}

PATHS = ["sample_EC{0}.Regions".format(x) for x in range(1, 5)]

CommonRegions = set.intersection(*[file_to_set(path) for path in PATHS])

print CommonRegions
```

Thanks to @user3789032 for reminding me of `set.intersection`.

With this, you can set `PATHS` to whatever set of files you need to process. If you want to read the paths as command line parameters, use:

```
import sys
PATHS = sys.argv[1:]
```

If you want to read the paths in from standard input:

```
import sys
PATHS = [line.strip() for line in sys.stdin.readlines()]
```

If you want to read the paths in from a file specified on the command line:

```
import sys
with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
    PATHS = [line.strip() for line in f]
```